# Umbrella heade with directories exist next to it?

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode15

```
target 'SDK' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at '.../Sources/SDK/include/SDK.h', but directories exist next to it: .../Sources/SDK/include/cpp, /.../Sources/SDK/include/hx; consider removing them
```

But these directories contain the headers that my umbrella header is including.  Am I *required* to flatten the hierarchy in order to use an umbrella header for a C++ target with SPM?